# Setting cookies with javascript in Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, cookies, browser

I need to set cookies in Javascript, before the browser will begin to fetch images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie='hidpi=1; path=/';
</script>

<img src="happyNY.png" alt=""/>
```

It works fine in all desktop browsers and in iOS Safari. They are fetching the images with HTTP cookie header had been set.

```
GET /happyNY.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
…
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Cookie: hidpi=1
```

The problem is, that iOS Chrome ignores cookies, while requesting the images.

```
GET /happyNY.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
…
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
```

If you click F5, then iOS Chrome will request image with HTTP cookie header correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found, was to reload the page for Chrome iOS browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS')>=0 && document.cookie.indexOf('hidpi')<0)
  {
    document.cookie='hidpi=1; path=/';
    window.location.reload();
  }

  document.cookie='hidpi=1; path=/';
</script>
```

Comment: I found this same solution the hard way. Chrome iOS takes a reload like Dionis is doing here to work properly. Glad to see this answer here. Cheers